# Only first item display when applying CSS on navigation

Tags: jquery, html, mysql, css

I have tried following code for navigation in which i am retrieving category names and subcategories from mysql database table. The problem is when i don't apply css to it. It shows all the subcategories under its relevent category. But when i applied some css to this code it only shows the first relevant subcategory name on hover to category name. Here is my code and css. I am stuck and can't understand where i am doing it wrong. Any suggestions please.

```js
$(function() {
  if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version.substr(0,1)<7)
  {
    $('li').has('ul').mouseover(function(){
      $(this).children('ul').show();
    }).mouseout(function(){
      $(this).children('ul').hide();
    })
  }
});
```

```css
body
{
  width: 960px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}

/* Main menu */

#menu
{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 0 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  background: #111;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0, #111),color-stop(1, #444));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
  background: linear-gradient(#444, #111);
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #9c9c9c;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #9c9c9c;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #9c9c9c;
}

#menu li
{
  float: left;
  padding: 0 0 10px 0;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 0;
}

#menu a
{
  float: left;
  height: 25px;
  padding: 0 25px;
  color: #999;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font: bold 12px/25px Arial, Helvetica;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
}

#menu li:hover > a
{
  color: #fafafa;
}

*html #menu li a:hover /* IE6 */
{
  color: #fafafa;
}

#menu li:hover > ul
{
  display: block;
}

/* Sub-menu */

#menu ul
{
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99999;
  background: #444;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0, #111),color-stop(1, #444));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
  background: linear-gradient(#444, #111);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#menu ul ul
{
  top: 0;
  left: 150px;
}

#menu ul li
{
  float: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111111, 0 2px 0 #777777;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111111, 0 2px 0 #777777;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111111, 0 2px 0 #777777;
}

#menu ul li:last-child
{
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

#menu ul a
{
  padding: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 130px;
  height: auto;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  float: none;
  text-transform: none;
}

*html #menu ul a /* IE6 */
{
  height: 10px;
}

*:first-child+html #menu ul a /* IE7 */
{
  height: 10px;
}

#menu ul a:hover
{
  background: #0186ba;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#04acec,  #0186ba);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#04acec), to(#0186ba));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#04acec,  #0186ba);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#04acec,  #0186ba);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(#04acec,  #0186ba);
  background: linear-gradient(#04acec,  #0186ba);
}

#menu ul li:first-child > a
{
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

#menu ul li:first-child > a:after
{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  top: -8px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #444;
}

#menu ul ul li:first-child a:after
{
  left: -8px;
  top: 12px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 8px solid #444;
}

#menu ul li:first-child a:hover:after
{
  border-bottom-color: #04acec;
}

#menu ul ul li:first-child a:hover:after
{
  border-right-color: #04acec;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}


#menu ul li:last-child > a
{
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}

/* Clear floated elements */
#menu:after
{
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}

* html #menu             { zoom: 1; } /* IE6 */
*:first-child+html #menu { zoom: 1; } /* IE7 */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">

  <li>
    <a href="#">Categories</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">CSS</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Item 11</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 12</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 13</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 14</a></li>
        </ul>    
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Graphic design</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Item 21</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 22</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 23</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 24</a></li>
        </ul>    
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Development tools</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Item 31</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 32</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 33</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 34</a></li>
        </ul>    
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Web design</a>    
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Item 41</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 42</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 43</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 44</a></li>
        </ul> 
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w6jpxtc9/1/

Comment: Do you have a live demo?

Comment: @DaMaGeX i copied this css from http://red-team-design.com/css3-dropdown-menu/

Comment: Can you convert the `php` code to `html`? Or better, convert all your code to a snippet.

Comment: @MoshFeu i want something like this https://jsfiddle.net/w6jpxtc9/1/ . I just get the first subcategory when i hover on category

Comment: Is that the exact code you're using? Because the demo looks okay to me...

Comment: @Yumecosmos yes i am using the exact code but tried this with php and mysql

Comment: @tabia Not sure I'm following. From the browser's perspective it shouldn't matter whether you're generating the code with php or not. Are you 100% positive this is the output you're getting from your server-side script?

Comment: I don't see any problems on your jsfiddle. What is your problem again?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the first version of the code you posted, I think your issue might be here:

```
<ul>
    <a href="#"><?=$ro['s_cat_name']?></a>
</ul>
```

Seems like it's missing an `<li>`. Also, your second-level `<li>` is closing inside the subcategories loop; I'm guessing it should be outside.